# Format for AWS API Access Key ID and Secret Access Key . Getting exception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

```
This is the format I have used for API accesskey and secret key in AwsCredentials.properties
    # Fill in your AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key
    # http://aws.amazon.com/security-credentials
    accessKey = accessKeyHere
    secretKey = secretKeyHere
```

I got this exception when I tried to compile the code. I have already installed the toolkit for eclips and I am using eclipse kepler

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:56)
        at test_toolkit.GetS3Object.main(GetS3Object.java:19)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

I have tried many methods, also by adding commons-logging-1.1.3  jar then it gives httpclient exception , I searched a lot and then also added this jar httpcomponents-client-4.3.3   but nothing worked for me.
Can some one please guide me that how I can start an EC2 instance from my local system and then I want to attach an EBS volume to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've only copied jackson core and jackson databind, you need jackson annotations to use the ObjectMapper.

For example, make sure you have something like this:

```
        [16:32:01]:/android-project/libs     master]$ ls -lAF
    total 2112
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jeffamaphone  staff   33525 Jun 18 16:06 jackson-annotations-2.0.2.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jeffamaphone  staff  193693 Jun  7 16:42 jackson-core-2.0.2.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jeffamaphone  staff  847121 Jun 18 15:22 jackson-databind-2.0.2.jar
```

Hope so this resolve your headache.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it worked for me. I added these earlier but was using different version of jackson-databind.  Finally got rid of exceptions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually nothing has gone wrong with the code, Since you didn't posted the code but still I want to share a tip with you : -

Please check the class name and the file name, both should be same.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

This type of error appears due to mismatch of Class name and File name.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually my teacher posted the code and it is supposed to be correct but when I tried to run it , it keep on giving me exceptions. I add one jar and then a new error appear . currently I am getting this exception    

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper

Comment: Please check any json object are setting the value to null by default.

Comment: If you've only copied jackson core and jackson databind, you need jackson annotations to use the ObjectMapper.